# C++: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list (compiled with clang++ 3.4)

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

I tried to write a very simple progressbar class. I put everything into progressBar.h, and created a minimal test case. I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04, using clang++ 3.4. I included -std=c++11 flag. The test case created a new ProgressBar Object and call the member function displayProgress(double). I included  and  in ProgressBar.h.

Here is my code:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

class ProgressBar
{
private:
    std::ostream& out;
    int width;

public:
    ProgressBar(std::ostream& out, int _width = 80)：out(out) {
        width = _width - 9;
    }

    void displayProgress(double percentage) {
        out << "\r[" << fixed << setprecision(2) << percentage * 100 << "%]";
        for (int i = 0; i < width * percentage; ++i) out << "=";
        if (percentage != 1) out << ">";
        else out << "O";
    }
};
```

Here is the error message:

```
In file included from test.cpp:2:
./progressBar.h:11:52: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    ProgressBar(std::ostream& out, int _width = 80)：out(out) {
                                                   ^
                                                   ;
test.cpp:8:4: error: no member named 'displayProgress' in 'ProgressBar'
        p.displayProgress(0.5);
        ~ ^
2 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 13):

`：` is not `:`. What you've got there in your code is a [FULLWIDTH COLON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff1a/index.htm) instead of just a [COLON](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003a/index.htm).

Replace `：` with `:`.